# Leibniz integral rule help

Tags: derivatives, leibniz-integral-rule

Let
$$I:=\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} \left[\epsilon \int^{b(\epsilon)}_{a(\epsilon)} x f(x) dx \right]_{\epsilon = 0}.$$
My textbook claims that, as a consequence of the Leibniz integral rule:

$$I=  \int^{b(0)}_{a(0)} x f(x)dx  + f(b(0)) \ b(0) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} b(\epsilon) \right)_{\epsilon=0} - f(a(0)) \ a(0) \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} a(\epsilon) \right)_{\epsilon =0} .$$

I found that (by an application of the product rule):

$$I= \int^{b(0)}_{a(0)} x f(x)dx + \left[ \epsilon \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} \int^{b(\epsilon)}_{a(\epsilon)} x f(x) dx  \right) \right]_{\epsilon = 0} = \int^{b(0)}_{a(0)} x f(x)dx + 0$$

which appears to be in contradiction with the first claim...

Am I missing something here ?

Comment: *You* are correct. What is your textbook?

Answer (score 0):

What you are given is suitable for Product Rule & you get the Correct $I$.
It is not suitable for Leibniz Integral Rule due to Extra Product term , which the text book is wronging ignoring.

Let us rewrite it to make it suitable for Leibniz Integral Rule :

$$ I = \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} \left[\int^{b(\epsilon)}_{a(\epsilon)} \epsilon x f(x) dx \right]_{\epsilon = 0} $$

Consequence of the Leibniz Integral Rule is now :

$$  \begin{align} I &=  \int^{b(0)}_{a(0)} x f(x)dx  + \left(  \epsilon f(b(0)) \ b(0) \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} b(\epsilon) \right)_{\epsilon=0} - \left(  \epsilon f(a(0)) \ a(0) \frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon} a(\epsilon) \right)_{\epsilon =0} \\
&= \int^{b(0)}_{a(0)} x f(x)dx  + 0
 \end{align} $$

It will match with Product Rule ...